# VBA: splitting a two-dimensional array

Tags: arrays, vba

In vba I have a two-dimensional array that I need to split somehow into two separate arrays. I have looked at the split function but I don't see how that would solve my problem.

The array looks like:

```
shift(1)
   shift(1,1)
   shift(1,2)
   shift(1,3)
   and so on...
```

Now, what I need is to split this like so:

```
shift(1)
   shift(1,1)

shift(2)
   shift (2,1) -- was shift(1,2)
   shift (2,2) -- was shift(1,3)
```

What's the best way to do this?

Thanks for helping me out here!

Comment: split() will be of no use, you would need to loop and build the new arrays element by element

Comment: Thanks, @AlexK. I did that now. Just wanted to know if there was an easier way.